# "Network Scan" gives "DHCPServer FAILED", but it's checking the wrong address

Tags: windows-xp, networking, dhcp, ping, dhcp-server

When I do a "Windows Help and Support Center" "Network Scan" on my XP SP3 machine, it tests a very long list of various things.   All are marked "OK" except:

```
> DHCPServer 192.168.0.1 (FAILED)
> Pinging 192.168.0.1, request failed
```

My router, and my Network Property tab are both set to 192.168.1.1, *NOT* 192.168.0.1.

Other machines on my network correctly check 192.168.1.1, and report OK, when I do the same Network Scan.

Where would I set (fix) that value?  Why does Windows think it needs to scan/check the WRONG address?  (Thus failing.)

Help!

```
UPDATE:

I did find these 8 wrong values in my registry:
> DhcpDefaultGateWay 192.168.0.1
> DhcpIPAddress      192.168.0.2  (.2 ????)
> DhcpNameServer     192.168.0.1
> DhcpServer         192.168.0.1
> DhcpDefaultGateWay 192.168.0.1
> DhcpIPAddress      192.168.0.2  (.2 ????)
> DhcpNameServer     192.168.0.1
> DhcpServer         192.168.0.1
```

Notice the "suggested DhcpIpAddress fix" isn't even ".1" anyway.

Sounds like things are pretty messed up for me.

Answer (score 2):

Open regedit as an administrator.

Check all the subkeys of the registry key below (they will be long and resemble this, "{9B5A7831-1D50-4353-9583-50C4245EF413}"):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
```

As you check each subkey, look for this key in the right pane, "`DhcpServer`", with the value "`192.168.0.1`". Double-click it and edit it to be "`192.168.1.1`".

You may need to reboot. I am not sure.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Thanks!  Any idea how my values got messed up?  Virus?  AntiVirus?

Comment: I cannot be 100% sure as to why, but virus is VERY unlikely.

Comment: Since you had so many bad entries (I figured there would be only one based on your question), why don't you go into device manager, and delete the adapter, and then scan for changes to re-find and re-add it. That will probably fix it.

Comment: *> so many bad entries* Huh? Do you mean the items in the Update? That’s likely because the router’s IP used to be `192.168.0.1` and the NIC was using that, then she changed the router’s IP `192.168.1.1` and now the NIC needs to be updated to reflect that. My guess is that she has a hard-coded static setting somewhere.

Comment: I think that would be obvious if she had her IP address settings set statically, and I don't think that she would have gotten "DHCPServer 192.168.0.1 (FAILED)". My thoughts were that it is somehow not finding and updating the DHCP server, and thus, the rest of the settings after.

Comment: @KCotreau: I don't think you are suppose update those entries.  the DHCPIpAdess isn't the IPaddress of the DHCP server, but rather the host address that the DHCP server assigns to your machine. If anything, it looks like  the DHCP is going the computer wrong settings.

Comment: @surfasb I was only advocating setting which DHCP server to find, assuming that it was somehow not finding the right one. Oh crap I looked at the wrong IP addres, you are RIGHT, the one she needed to edit was "DhcpServer". I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address in the registry entires you listed are `.2` instead of `.1` because those are for your system, while the ones with `.1` are for the router. This is perfectly normal.

What you need to do is to go to `Control Panel->Network Places`, right-click your NIC/connection and select Properties. Now double-click `IP4 (TCP/IPv4)` (or select it and click Properties).

Are you using static settings or is it set to auto?

If you have static settings, check the gateway. Is it `192.168.0.1`? Change it to `192.168.1.1`. Also check the `Alternate Configuration` tab and make the same change.

If you are using auto settings (ie DHCP), click `Advanced`. Now look at the `Default gateways` list box in the `IP Settings tab`. What’s in there? If there is a `192.168.0.1`, click Edit and change it to `192.168.1.1`

Finally, if all else fails, do a search-and-replace in the registry (but don’t resort to that if you can avoid it by using the provided dialog interfaces to make the changes).